# pd.Timedelta conversion on a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a dataframe column to a timedelta but am having issues.  The format that the column comes in looks like '+XX:XX:XX' or '-XX:XX:XX'

My dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['+06:00:00', '-04:00:00'],})
```

My approach:

```
    df['time'] = pd.Timedelta(df['time'])
```

However, I get the error:

```
    ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible
```

When I do a simpler example:

```
    time = pd.Timedelta('+06:00:00')
```

I get my desired output:

```
    Timedelta('0 days 06:00:00')
```

What would be the approach if I wanted to convert a series into a timedelta with my desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

> ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta
>   or convertible

What you are passing to `pd.Timedelta()` is none of the above data types:

```
>>> type(df['time'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Probably what you want it:

```
>>> [pd.Timedelta(x) for x in df['time']]
[Timedelta('0 days 06:00:00'), Timedelta('-1 days +20:00:00')]
```

Or:

```
>>> df['time'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
0            06:00:00
1   -1 days +20:00:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

See more examples in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html).

Comment: Thanks, the .apply() method works and is what I was looking for.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9):

I would strongly recommend to use specifically designed and vectorized (i.e. very fast) method: [to_timedelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
In [40]: pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
Out[40]:
0            06:00:00
1   -1 days +20:00:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

**Timing** against a 200K rows DF:

```
In [41]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [42]: df.shape
Out[42]: (200000, 1)

In [43]: %timeit pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
1 loop, best of 3: 891 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit df['time'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.15 s per loop

In [45]: %timeit [pd.Timedelta(x) for x in df['time']]
1 loop, best of 3: 5.52 s per loop
```